# Problem including eigenspace and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given $A \in M_n(F)$ and $V_j(A)\ :=N(A^j)$, where $N$ is the nullity.
>
> $(a)$ Prove $V_j\subseteq V_{j+1}, \ \forall j,$ and there exists $l\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $j<l: V_j \subset V_{j+1},$ and for all $j \geq l: V_j=V_{j+1}$. That is:
>
> $$\{0\} \subset V_1 \subset V_2 \subset\dots\subset V_l = V_{l+1}=V_{l+2}=\dots$$
>
> $(b)$ Let $\lambda \in F$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity $k$ and multiple $r$ as root of the minimal polynomial $m_A$.
>
> Let us look at the spaces sequence $V_j(A-\lambda I).$
>
> Prove that in this case, $l=r$ and $\dim V_l(A-\lambda I)=k$

I proved $(a)$, but I'm struggling with $(b)$.

I'm having hard time connecting the line between the minimal polynomial and $N(A^j)$.

I think Jordan might help me here, but not sure how to proceed.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Jordan form, then it suffices to note that $\dim(V_j(A - \lambda I)) - \dim(V_{j-1}(A - \lambda I))$ is the number of Jordan blocks associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ with size at least $j$.

Comment: I can see that, but I can't see how to proceed. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: From there, note that the algebraic multiplicity is the total of the sizes of the blocks associated with $\lambda$, and $r$ is the size of the largest Jordan block associated with $\lambda$.

Comment: Forgive me, but now I can't understand the note you mentioned in your answer. Mind explaining why is it true? I do know the attributes you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Look what happens when you take the powers of a Jordan block associated with $\lambda = 0$: whenever $J^k \neq 0$, we have $\dim N(J^{k+1})  = \dim N(J^k) + 1$.   This goes on until we have $J^k = 0$.  Of course, when you take the $k$th power of a block diagonal matrix, you're just taking the $k$th power of each block entry.

Comment: What do you mean by $+1?$

Comment: Oh, excuse me: that should read $\dim(N(J^{k+1})) = \dim(N(J^k)) + 1$

Comment: Okay, I understand that. How does that imply the number of Jordan blocks associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda ?$

Comment: Suppose without loss of generality that $A$ is in Jordan normal form.  Notice that $A - \lambda I$ will now have Jordan blocks associated with zero wherever there was a Jordan block associated with $\lambda$.  If we look at the nullities of the successive powers, then it is precisely the blocks associated with $\lambda$ which cause the changes (if $J$ is a Jordan block not associated with zero, then $\dim N(J^k) = 0$).

Comment: Okay, I understood that. So we have $\dim(V_j(A- \lambda I)) - \dim(V_{j-1}(A- \lambda I)) $ blocks of size at least $j$. How can we get the size of the biggest block out of that ?

Comment: @Itay4 saying that $r$ is the biggest block size is the same as saying that $0 = \dim(V_j(A- \lambda I)) - \dim(V_{j-1}(A- \lambda I))$ is the number of blocks of size at least $j$ for any $j > r$.